# How do I render an image with display options?

Tags: views, theming

I would like to render an image, with responsive styles at the top of a view.

The approach I have been using is to try to access to the full array that you get when calling `render($content['field_banner'])` from the view template.

I am using:

- The views-view-bvt-tables--class-timetable--page.tpl.php template
- The Picture module to map images styes to screen sizes
- The Profile2 module

I have found the image using this code.

```
$profile_row = $result[0];
render($profile_row->field_field_studio_banner);
```

It gives a different result, compared to the following code, used in profile2.tpl.php.

```
print render($content['field_studio_banner']);
```

I can't see display properties, such as `#formatter = picture` in the view array.

How do I set any display property?

Comment: Most images allow styles to be set by using the Views interface. Are you sure you cannot set it there?

Comment: Ah you are right. I was too busy playing with the template and forgot about the views config.